# Equivalent StackOverflow-like site for Java design discussions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site like stack overflow where you are allowed to ask Java application tech design questions of other members? e.g. Opinions on what aspects of Java EE 6 to use and what design patterns to use?

I know and understand that/why these types of questions are not allowed on StackOverflow, since questions/answers are supposed to be objective and not subjective, but the use case exists where folks want to be able to get expert opinions on tech design. Does a site exist for this?

Comment: I would have though that such questions are eligible on SO... *Edit:* Ah I see.

Comment: Why not use chat? There ought to be  a Java room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is the closest to what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is really conceptual, go with [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/?as=1).